# how to add multiple JSON data links to Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a lot of links which has JSON data inside and i need the data from links to mysql, what could be fastest way for that ?

Is it possible to modify this code below to make it able to read from multiple urls ?

```
<?php
    //connect to mysql db
    $con = mysql_connect("username","password","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    //connect to the employee database
    mysql_select_db("employee", $con);

    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('empdetails.json');

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get the employee details
    $id = $data['empid'];
    $name = $data['personal']['name'];
    $gender = $data['personal']['gender'];
    $age = $data['personal']['age'];
    $streetaddress = $data['personal']['address']['streetaddress'];
    $city = $data['personal']['address']['city'];
    $state = $data['personal']['address']['state'];
    $postalcode = $data['personal']['address']['postalcode'];
    $designation = $data['profile']['designation'];
    $department = $data['profile']['department'];

    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp(empid, empname, gender, age, streetaddress, city, state, postalcode, designation, department)
    VALUES('$id', '$name', '$gender', '$age', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$postalcode', '$designation', '$department')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can run this in a loop, provided you are able to feed it the list of links from the JSON needs to be downloaded.

Comment: its not possible to read JSON url's from excel file for example ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have updated your code to read from a `.csv` file. You can update it to read from an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of reading url's from a excel file.

I am using http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/.

File - urls.xls.

It assumes this excel contains url's in the first column.

```
<?php
//connect to mysql db
$con = mysql_connect("username","password","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//connect to the employee database
mysql_select_db("employee", $con);

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("urls.xls",false);
$rows = $data->rowcount(0);

for( $i=0;$i<$rows;$i++ ) {
    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($data->val($i,0));

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get the employee details
    $id = $data['empid'];
    $name = $data['personal']['name'];
    $gender = $data['personal']['gender'];
    $age = $data['personal']['age'];
    $streetaddress = $data['personal']['address']['streetaddress'];
    $city = $data['personal']['address']['city'];
    $state = $data['personal']['address']['state'];
    $postalcode = $data['personal']['address']['postalcode'];
    $designation = $data['profile']['designation'];
    $department = $data['profile']['department'];

    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp(empid, empname, gender, age, streetaddress, city, state, postalcode, designation, department)
    VALUES('$id', '$name', '$gender', '$age', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$postalcode', '$designation', '$department')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.